# Which class should the conversion code belong to?

Tags: oop, class, type-conversion

If I want to cast from class `Foo` to another class `Bar`, should the code for the conversion belong in the `Foo` or `Bar` class?

```
Foo f

Bar b = f.ToBar()
```

Or:

```
Foo f

Bar b = Bar.FromFoo(f)
```

The latter could be rewritten as a constructor rather than a static method, but that's not the point of this question.

Of course in many cases, not being able to modify one of the classes makes the decision for you. For example if I had a custom class `Foo` and wanted to convert it to an integer.

Comment: From Bar makes more sense, since we are creating an object of type Bar, it is natural to encapsulate, all ways of creating Bar, in it. Also having a static factory method, does make more sense than using the Constructor.

Comment: Two possible answers, and both given. Good start.

Comment: Why to create conversion method instead of constructor? My opinion is that new Bar(f) is more logical.

Comment: @Betlista, I agree, but `To` and `From` show the question much more clearly. It is not relevant anyway.

Comment: There is a lot of points of view. For example if you care about coupling, there are 3 ways - to couple Foo with Bar (f.ToBar), to couple Bar with Foo (Bar.FromFoo(f)) or you can create conversion "service" S.convertToBar(f). It is always about what you need ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look at it this way: whose concern is the conversion? Should Foo know or care that some other class called Bar, is using it in some ways? Of course not. Because, what if there are MANY other classes that use Foo, in various ways, then should Foo go ahead and take care of them too? No.
Therefore, first important point is that this functionality has to be implemented on Bar's side. And then, comes the question of secondary importance: how to implement it. Here, implementing it as a constructor, as others have pointed out, is more logical and inline with oop principle.

Answer (score 1):

The operation should typically live on the object it affects, so in this case it would be f.ToBar().